Expression for dividing by 100, based on the number of factors, minus one factor.
I'm trying to convey a way to calculate the aggregate device downtime in a proposal that I'm writing, and I'm struggling, since I don't have a formal higher-math background.
My premise is that, if x depends on y, their combined uptime is (X * Y), and since it needs to be expressed in percentage, it can be expressed as:
Aggregate Downtime = 100 / (X * Y)
For example: 90 = 100 / (100 * 95)
This needs to scale to more than two devices. My problem is that I do not know how to express that if there's multiple devices.
For example: If I'm calculating the aggregate downtime of 4 devices, my calculation becomes: 90.25 = (100 / (100 / (100 / (100 * 100 * 95 * 95))))
(I'm not sure if this is how you express that, but notice I'm only dividing by 100, three times, instead of 4 times.)
How would I express that, and what is this type of math called?
Thank you for your time.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

If you have two devices that both have to work for the system to be successful you multiply the availabilities, assuming these are independent.  If the availabilities are $X$ and $Y$, expressed as fractions of the time (between $0$ and $1$) the overall availability is $X\cdot Y$.  The fraction of the time the system is unavailable is $1-X \cdot Y$.  You should not be dividing.  If $X$ and $Y$ are percentages you need to divide each one by $100$, then multiply the whole thing by $100$ to get a percentage, so the percentage uptime is $\frac {X \cdot Y}{100}.$  If you have more devices you put them into the product, so for three you have availability in percent is $\frac {X \cdot Y \cdot Z}{100^2}$ and so on.

Excellent! I knew I was going about this the incorrect way. Yes, X and Y are precentages in our case.
The problem I'm trying to solve is that I want to be able to calculate the total downtime/uptime of each Access-segment of our network- from Fixed/Mobile Wireless Boradband, to the GPON and Metro Ethernet segments and so on.
This should give me a usable measurement of service availability, something we can improve on.
Thanks you so much, Ross!
